# AttributeError in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)

Tags: machine-learning, anaconda, jupyter

I am beginner to Machine Learning. I am using "from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer to" module and it throws error. I am not sure why it throws error. I am using

Here is the screenshot of error
[image: !]

[image]

Comment: The error message is cut off

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added whole image.

Comment: This is why its better to copy-paste the error message, rather than screenshot...